# use dplyr to get list items from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, microsoft365r

I have a dataframe being returned from Microsoft365R:

```
SKA_student <- structure(list(name = "Computing SKA 2021-22.xlsx", size = 22266L, 
             lastModifiedBy = 
               structure(list(user = 
                      structure(list(email = "my@email.com", 
                                     id = "8ae50289-d7af-4779-91dc-e4638421f422", 
                                     displayName = "Name, My"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)), 
             fileSystemInfo = structure(list(
               createdDateTime = "2021-09-08T16:03:38Z", 
               lastModifiedDateTime = "2021-09-16T00:09:04Z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can return all the `lastModifiedBy` data through:

```
SKA_student %>% select(lastModifiedBy)

lastModifiedBy.user.email               lastModifiedBy.user.id lastModifiedBy.user.displayName
1              my@email.com 8ae50289-d7af-4779-91dc-e4638421f422                        Name, My
```

But if I want a specific item in the `lastModifiedBy` list, it doesn't work, e.g.:

```
SKA_student %>% select(lastModifiedBy.user.email)

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `lastModifiedBy.user.email` doesn't exist.
```

I can get this working through base, but would really like a dplyr answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function allows you to flatten all the list columns (I found this ages ago on SO but can't find the original post for credit)

```
SO_flat_cols <- function(data) {
    ListCols <- sapply(data, is.list)
    cbind(data[!ListCols], t(apply(data[ListCols], 1, unlist)))
}
```

Then you can select as you like.

```
SO_flat_cols (SKA_student) %>%
  select(lastModifiedBy.user.email)
```

Alternatively you can get to the end by recursively pulling the lists

```
SKA_student %>%
  pull(lastModifiedBy) %>%
  pull(user) %>%
  select(email)
```

Comment: this is pretty neat, the annoying thing about unnest_wider(lastModifiedBy) is that some of the fileds returned by Microsoft365R have the same names, this solution deals with that

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

SKA_student %>% 
  unnest_wider(lastModifiedBy) %>% 
  select(email)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  email       
  <chr>       
1 my@email.com
```